# Ruby w/ Sinatra (ERB): my link is throwing a syntax error, but it didn't in rails... how do I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

```
  <%= link_to( { :controller => 'board', :action => 'start_game', :human_is_first => true  }, :remote => true) do %>
    <span>Yes</span>

  <% end %>
```

works perfectly in rails 3, how do i get it to work with sinatra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link_to` a helper method from the module ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.

You would need to create your own method or output the html `<a>` tag to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Is there anyway to include ActionView?

Comment: I'm not there if there's an easy way to do that. I would think you would need to include a lot of files. 

Why not just use Rails for your application or make your own link_to method?